# How do I open .cvh files? This is apparently an extremely rare format

Tags: web-apps

I have an old Sharper Image recording device  that took digital recordings. The recordings play on that device fine.
It is a Sharper Image Cx602 Mp3 Handheld Digital Voice Recorder with MP3
A picture of it is here https://i.imgur.com/BZp0vdz.jpg

An eBay site with the device is https://www.ebay.com/itm/Sharper-Image-Cx602-Mp3-Handheld-Digital-Voice-Recorder-/253518920974

I was able to download the files, but I cannot find a program to open the .cvh format on my computer.
I have tried this with Windows 10 and Linux Mint.
I have used every online site I can find to try to open it with no luck.
I no longer have access to the device itself, just the files.

If I try to open the document with any program I have found, it says it doesn't recognize the format.

I've already been scolded for not saying which sites or programs I tried :) I didn't keep a list,  but I tried all the normal preloaded programs along with all the sites that say "Open any format" etc. that I could find.

I was hoping to find that apparently rare person who will recognize the format and say, "Oh yeah, I know what you do."

So that's really the best I can do on information, and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, what is the exact model of the recorder?

Comment: Hi, thanks. I believe it is the Sharper Image Cx602 Mp3 Handheld Digital Voice Recorder with MP3 # 3165 u  Unfortunately it is in a storage locker 2000 miles away, so I can't be sure, but this appeared on eBay, and it looks exactly the same.

Comment: To be thorough, I'll include the eBay link, which will surely expire and which may not be allowed on this forum (?) https://www.ebay.com/itm/Sharper-Image-Cx602-Mp3-Handheld-Digital-Voice-Recorder-/253518920974

Comment: Imgur link to photo of the device. https://i.imgur.com/BZp0vdz.jpg

Comment: It is allowed but not really worth including indeed. Anyways, please edit the question whenever you add new details.

Comment: Have you tried FFmpeg?  They list the compatible file types by name and not suffix so maybe there is a match.   https://ffmpeg.org/about.html

Comment: ffmpeg is still beyond my understanding. I've learned a little about it, but it's not a steep learning curve with that program, I find.